# Change RequireJS Module Method After It Has Been Loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to alter a RequireJS module function after it has been loaded? For example.

```
define(['favorite_fruit'], [], function() {
  function fruitName() {
    return 'apple';
  }
  return { fruit: fruitName }
});
```

And I would like to change the function `fruitName` to return 'banana' from a global javascript function.

I've tried things like:

```
require.s.contexts._.defined['favorite_fruit'].fruit = function() { return 'banana'; };
```

But wherever this module gets used it still returns `apple` instead of `banana`. Maybe the module object is getting stored somewhere else that can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions here.

## Solution #1

Amend the module itself and add setter:

```ja
define(['favorite_fruit'], [], function() {
  var fruit = 'apple';

  function fruitName() {
    return 'apple';
  }

  function setFruitName(name) {
    fruit = name;
  }

  return { fruit: fruitName, setFruit: setFruitName }
});
```

## Solution #2

Undefine the module and define it again:

```js
requirejs.undef('favorite_fruit');
define(['favorite_fruit'], [], function() {
  function fruitName() {
    return 'banana';
  }
  return { fruit: fruitName }
});
```